# How to Access the Result of GET Method From a Class?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, get, actionresult

I have a get method. This method calls an endpoint from a different project and gets customer information. I want to use this customer's information in another class. But I don't know how to access it.

It is an option to write the information I get with the method into the database and then read it from there, but the number of customers may be high and there may have been an update in the customer information. That's why I have to call whenever I need it.

My `GetCustomerInformation(customerIdList)` method returns that : `return Ok(customerInfoList`);

And when I want to get `customerInfoList` in another class, I tried something like that:

```
var customerList = _customerInfoController.GetCustomerInformation(customerIdList).Result;
```

It returns an `ActionResult`, how can I get the `customerInfoList` as `List`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that

```
var customerList =_customerInfoController.GetCustomerInformation(customerIdList)
```

is an external Web API call..
the type of `customerList` will be an `HttpResponseMessage`. So we need to covert that data into a string and then to a specific object and then you can access the list.

```
var response = customerList .Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var data= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<YourSpecificObject>>(response);
```

You may need to create a class with all the specified properties of customer list as `YourSpecificObject`..

Answer (score 0):

First add the project reference where API is located inside the project where you want to use it(image shown below)

[image]

Then your new class(in other project) can be implemented like this.

```
@using APIProject;
public IList<YourSpecificObject> customerList { get; set; }
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(customerIdList)
{
  customerList =_customerInfoController.GetCustomerInformation(customerIdList)
}
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.